# Snake line with an arrowhead in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

in my code i need to draw some Feynmann diagrams with several lines like this one:

[image: snakeline]

To draw this image, i usually use this code:

```
\tikzset{White/.style={
  draw=white, 
  postaction={decorate}, 
  decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[black]{triangle 45} } }
  }
}
\tikzset{Snake/.style={decorate,decoration={snake}}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
  \node(A) {};
  \node (B) [right of=A] {};
  \draw[White] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[Snake] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But this kind of code, is unpractical, so i tried using:

```
\tikzstyle{MomPotential}=[fixed point arithmetic,
     decoration={snake},
     decorate,
     postaction={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.6 with arrow{triangle 45}}},
     decorate}
 ]
```

Here is the result:

[image: SnakeLine2]

As you can see, it's kind of ugly and it takes a lot to compile. Has anybody got any useful idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you accept `\blacktriangleright` symbol instead of `arrow{triangle 45}`, you don't need two decorations but one decoration and one node:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\tikzset{
    Snake/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}}
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {A};
\node[right=2cm of A] (B) {B};

\draw[Snake] (A)--(B) node[midway]{$\blacktriangleright$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is some way to define a style which automatically adds the node in the middle of the path? I tried with `execute at end to` key, but then the decoration is lost. I don't understand clearly the interactions...

Comment: @JLDiaz I don't know it. I've tried with `mark connection node` but snake decoration is also lost. The best I can do is defining a `myarrow/.style={midway,node contents=$\blacktriangleright$}` and use `\draw[Snake] (A)--(B) node[myarrow];`.

Comment: @JLDiaz A little advance with `mark connection node`: `\draw decorate[decoration={snake}] {
decorate [decoration={markings,mark connection node=my node, mark=at position .5 with {\node (my node) {$\blacktriangleright$};}}] {
 (0,2)--(5,2)}};`. But I don't know how to continue.